# CDN - white labeling

Tags: cdn, white-labelling

I own a video publishing media group and I'm planning to switch CDN's.
What I noticed from a lot of my competitors is that they "white label" the CDN.
One CDN provider confirmed to me that 3 competing companies use them as CDN, but when I go to their website, press "inspect" and play the content, when I go to the Network tab, all I see is some random IP or a domain name that was created specifically for the CDN, for example, if the company name is Video Group, then it'll be something like videogroup-cdn.com

How do they do that? Is that even possible to completely "white label" the CDN and not have it trace back to your supplier?

Comment: By "white label" do you mean mapping a custom domain to CDN endpoint?

Comment: @thelostspore yes

Comment: Typically you would create a CNAME record and map your custom domain to the CDN endpoint. Here are two examples/faqs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain and https://www.maxcdn.com/one/faq/). Note: a few more steps are involved if your domain is served over HTTPS (and typically SSL traffic is more expensive).

Comment: @thelostspore This is not exactly what I meant.

Here's an example, this is a video streaming site:​

Openload.co

When you dig into their source, this is their CDN:

http://oloadcdn.net

​Obviously, this is not really their CDN, they just white labelled it and made it yours. How exactly is this done?​

Comment: @amir which sub-domain points to oloadcdn.net? I can only see Openload.co is using Cloudflare through my this little tool http://www.whatsmycdn.com/.